# how to execute on mac /usr/bin/nohup

Tags: php, linux, macos

I am trying to create process on mac with nohup. Process is created but it is terminated immediately after creation. That process has command /usr/bin/wget http://local.domain/some.php. This is error from /var/log/system.log

```
(0x7fed9c80a940.anonymous.nohup[23454]): Bug: 12E55: launchd + 67394 [7DCC9489-2DF5-3807-83FA-EF5666EE8078]: 0x0
(0x7fed9c80a940.anonymous.nohup[23454]): Switching sessions is not allowed in the system Mach bootstrap.
(0x7fed9c80a940.anonymous.nohup[23454]): _vprocmgr_switch_to_session(): kr = 0x44c
```

I am stucked with this for few days now.

Process is created and executed on linux just fine.

Comment: Works just fine for me from the command line. Are you trying to do this from a PHP script? I see the PHP tag, but no mention of PHP in the question. If yes, is the PHP running in the context of a web server? or standalone? You should add some more info.

Comment: runs from a command line I know. when exec("nohup wget http://local.domain/some.php >  /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!") i got that error.

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem of context, I think. OsX isn't linux, it's based on BSD, but it's more than just a clone/*distro*. In it's very core, there's this *Mach* kernel, which is giving you the DOS (as in denial of service) treatment. I got this from this line:

```
Switching sessions is not allowed in the system Mach bootstrap
```

The problem, I think, is the way Mach treats the bootstrap context. `nohup` implies that the executed command can/may survive past logout in your case. When using `wget`, this does not compute:

> In Mach, the bootstrap task is assigned responsibility for looking up requests for Mach ports. As part of this effort, each Mach task is registered in one of two groups—either in the startup context or a user’s login context

You're forking a child using `nohup` in the login context which is, last time I checked, cleaned-up (sort of autoreleasepool-style) after logout. That doesn't really work, does it?
What's more: you're dealing with PHP, which responds to requests, yet at the same time, the forked child process may outlive the context that manages these very requests. Hence, this affects the use of `nohup`:

> Contexts also pose an issue for users running background jobs with nohup or users detaching terminal sessions using screen. There are times when it is perfectly reasonable for a program to survive past logout, but by default, this does not occur.

Bascially, because you're running a process from a login context, any child process automatically runs in the same (login) context. In your case, you're responsable for the child process, but `nohup` implies that it may outlive your context, an nobody is responsable for the process, which can be harmful. It requires the context to be startup. Which is sort of risky. I haven't found a clear-cut way around it, `su[do]` doesn't help, because that has no impact on the context.
The only way I can think of is for you to write a script/daemon that runs in the startup context, and idle's, waiting for you to pass the command to it, because any daemon running in the startup context will fork child processes in its own (startup) context. I gather that's how `httpd` works, anyway

Either that, or create a third context, but I couldn't tell you how to safely do that...

Source: [OSX Kernel programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/contexts/contexts.html)

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this. I will let you know result.